# vim variable declaration

Tags: vim

I added following line of code in .vimrc

```
let g:jslint_status = 'enabled'

if exists("jslint_status")
  echo jstlint_status
else
  echo 'not found'
endif
```

Error message

```
E121: Undefined variable: jstlint_status
E15: Invalid expression: jstlint_status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check your spelling. You're checking if `jslint_status`exists, but you're echoing `jstlint_status`. Notice that extra T - the third character in the misspelled variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I find myself in this kind of situation, I try searching for the variable and with `incrsearch` on you get to see whether all the relevant portions are highlighted.

In this case, if you had searched for `jstlint_status` sure enough the assignment operation wont be highlighted.

As kemp points out in the comments, you could hit `*` on the variable of instance and see if the assignment operation is highlighted or not. It amazes how useful `*` is. No wonder it is called the Super Star

Comment: that's a good technique. I love it. thanks. I was going word by word to ensure variables are spelled correctly.

Comment: For even faster searching, just press `*` on any keyword of interest.